# File operations failing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having the following issues in my code below,please provide inputs on where it is going wrong?

1. change_ignore_base.txt and change_ignore_file.txt are not getting created,where is it going wrong?
2. I see chagne_ignore has "\r" and "\n" appended,what is the smart way to strip off them and put them in a variable which can later be used to search.

change_ids.txt

```
206061
150362
147117
147441
143446
200912
```

change_ignore.txt

```
150362
147117
147441
143446
200914
```

Code

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_call

def sync (base_change):
    # open a file
    with open('change_ignore.txt') as f:
        change_ignore = f.readlines()
        print "change_ignore"
        print change_ignore

    with open('change_ids.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line=line.strip()
            print line
            if line <= base_change:
                print "IN line<=base_change"
                print line
                with open("change_ignore_base.txt", "a") as myfile:
                    myfile.write(line)
            if line in change_ignore:
                print "IN change_ignore"
                print line
                with open("change_ignore_file.txt", "a") as myfile:
                    myfile.write("line")
            if line > base_change and line not in change_ignore:
                pass


def main ():
    base_change=200913
    sync(base_change)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: guessing your conditions aren't met.  You might want to compare ints to ints.  btw, you can just use "for line in f.readlines()", or even, "for line in f".

Comment: @monkut - yes,conditions are failing ,that can be clearly seen as the print statements are not printing...need somehelp to figure out on where it is going wrong

Comment: when you read a line from a file, it is by default read as a string.  You want to make sure that if you need to compare it to an int, say 200913, then you need to convert the input line to an int.

Comment: @monkut - Is there a python built-in func to convert to int?

Comment: Did you solve the `not created` issue? If the file hasn't exist on disk, you want to use `w+`, `a+` to create them. You can read the file and break all the lines into items of a list. To do that, you can use `f.read().splitlines()`.

Comment: just perform `int("1")` actually `a` will create the file if hasn't exist. but in any case. try those suggestions above. i was above to get the files.

Comment: yes, as CppLearner mentioned, the function to convert a string to an int is called int().

Comment: @monkut and CppLearner - I am able to accomplish these ,now the issue is I need to remove these files at the start of subroutine otherwise they keep getting appended,I tried to use os.remove,using os.remove at the start of subroutine is giving compilation error" os.remove(change_ignore_base) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'change_ignore_base' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a mild adjustment to your program that I believe accomplishes what you want. Key points (as pointed out in the comments) are that you want to compare integers with integers, and that you should avoid opening/closing files multiple times (as was happening with the file appends inside the loop).

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_call

def sync(base_change):

    # Generate a list of integers based on your change_ignore file
    with open('change_ignore.txt', 'rb') as f:
        # Here we make a list of integers based on the file
        change_ignore = [int(line.strip()) for line in f]

    # Store your hits/misses in lists; that way you do not
    # need to continuously open/close files while appending
    change_ignore_base = []
    change_ignore_file = []

    # Now open the file of the IDs
    with open('change_ids.txt', 'rb') as f:
        # Iterate over the file itself
        for line in f:
            # Convert the line to an integer (note that this
            # implicitly removes the newline characters)
            # However we are going to write 'line' to our list,
            # which will keep the newline (more on that later)
            num = int(line)
            print num

            # Now we are comparing ints with ints
            # I'm assuming the print statements are for debugging,
            # so we offset them with some space, making it so that
            # any relevant hits are indented under a number
            if num <= base_change:
                print "  IN line<=base_change"
                change_ignore_base.append(line)
            if num in change_ignore:
                print "  IN change_ignore"
                change_ignore_file.append(line)
            if num > base_change and num not in change_ignore:
                pass

    # Now that you have lists containing the data for your new files,
    # write them (they already have newlines appended so writelines works)
    # You can use 'with' with two files in this way in Python 2.7+,
    # but it goes over 80 characters here so I'm not a huge fan :)
    with open('change_ignore_base', 'wb') as b, open('change_ignore_file', 'wb') as f:
      b.writelines(change_ignore_base)
      f.writelines(change_ignore_file)


def main ():
    base_change=200913
    sync(base_change)

main()
```

This should create your files and print the following:

```
206061
150362
  IN line<=base_change
  IN change_ignore
147117
  IN line<=base_change
  IN change_ignore
147441
  IN line<=base_change
  IN change_ignore
143446
  IN line<=base_change
  IN change_ignore
200912
  IN line<=base_change
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,one small doubt,I want to delete the files created namely "change_ignore_file.txt" and "change_ignore_base.txt" at the start of subroutine..am planning to use os.remove,do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: using os.remove at the start of subroutine is giving compilation error"    os.remove(change_ignore_base)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'change_ignore_base' referenced before assignment"

Comment: @user1927396 No problem. As for removing the file, `os.remove` should be fine. However you actually don't have to delete them if you don't want to - opening a file in write mode (as indicated by the `wb`) will truncate the file and write the new contents. Therefore if that is acceptable, the above should work. However if you want to delete the file, I would suggest importing `os.path` and then checking to see if the file exists first (`os.path.exists('path/to'file')`); if so, you then pass the string name of the file to `os.remove` to remove it. Hope that helps :)

Comment: I didnt realize its a wb,that would work actually.thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks,I have one question,why should we open in binary mode "wb",file just contains ASCII characters..is there any advantage of using binary mode?

Comment: @user1927396 Naw, you should be fine without it - just a habit I've gotten into after a while :) I use it because it helps makes things more platform-compatible (since I sometimes need to run things on Windows and on Linux), but if that won't be an issue for you then there shouldn't be any harm in just using `w`.

Comment: is there a harm if I leave them in binary mode even though I dont need?

Comment: @user1927396 No, should be fine - there are some simple transformations that go on behind the scenes (line separators changing, etc.), but it shouldn't have any effect on your program (however you can also remove it if you'd like - result should stay the same).